# I'm not receiving the password reset email link when I click on the Reset password in my Blogging Web App built using Django Framework

Tags: django, django-settings, django-email

I'm not receiving the password reset email link when I click on the Reset password in my Blogging Web App built using Django Framework, although the info "**An email has been sent with instructions to reset your password.**" is prompted as well.
I'm guessing something with my setting USER_HOST_EMAIL and USER_HOST_PASSWORD in the environment variables.
The settings.py in my Django setup looks like this:

```py
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get('EMAIL_HOST_USER')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD')
```

Any ideas on what could possibly be the problem?

Comment: Can you share some of the django logs?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific in this regard please? You mean logs specific to the action that I'm trying to perform? Views, settings, template changes etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the problem was with the URI or the port number since I happened to change the HOST email address to the one with no two-factor authentication. That apparently worked without any other changes needed!

Answer (score 0):

I use EMAIL_PORT = 465, try changing it, If not, show how you are leaving your URl so I can try to help you better

Comment: Hey Alex, 
I don't think the problem was with the URI or the port number since I happened to change the HOST email address to the one with no two-factor authentication. That apparently worked without any other changes needed!

Thanks!